# VCRedist dependencies with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, vcredist

I'm trying to release a simple app with `PyInstaller` to work on windows7-X64 without any dependencies. But I got some problem with `Microsoft VCRedist`. In my host PC, I installed VCRedist 2015 and generated executable normally (not standalone). The VCRedist DLL files `api-ms-win*.dll` was included as expected in the generated directory and it worked fine on the target machine without VCRedist. Then I tried to generate a standalone app but this time when I executed it on target machine I got this error:

> The procedure entry point ucrtbase_putch couldnot be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll.

I checked the generated Temp folder (_MEI*) and found out that the right DLLs are right there and somehow the executable cannot use them. I created a copy of (_MEI*) folder and put the standalone executable next to it and surprisingly it worked. It seems that some of those DLLs exist in the windows directory of the target machine and it is trying to load them instead of (_MEI*) directory.

I also read the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#windows) but didn't help much with this.

Comment: Could you solve this problem?

Comment: I couldn't. It seems that on X64 system,target need to install VCredist and it wouldn't provided by app itself.

Comment: We added a step in our build pipeline to also include the missing dlls at the right place.